# Can I use reflection to detect a control's support for Transparent background?

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I am using the following code to generically set a control's `BackColor` property to `Color.Transparent`:

```
protected override void OnItemAdded(ToolStripItemEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnItemAdded(e);
    Type t = e.Item.GetType();
    PropertyInfo pInfo = t.GetProperty("BackColor");
    if (pInfo != null)
        pInfo.SetValue(e.Item, Color.Transparent, null);
}
```

Of course, when the control in question doesn't support it, I get an `ArgumentException`.  So I would like to include a check for whether or not that support exists.

How can I accomplish this check?

Comment: Why do you need reflection here? `Item` is derived from `Control` so you can access `BackColor` property directly. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @Leri He definitely needs it, He needs to check whether `BackColor` can be set to `Color.Transparent` or not :)

Comment: @Leri That is incorrect.  The method is receiving `ToolStripItemEventArgs`, meaning that `e.Item` is a `ToolStripItem`, which does not derive from `Control`.

Comment: @DonBoitnott My bad. However, `ToolStripItem` has property [`BackColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.backcolor(v=vs.110).aspx). So my question remains valid.

Comment: @Leri Blindly setting that property is precisely why the question is necessary.  Try that on a `ToolStripTextBox`, for instance.

Comment: @DonBoitnott My environment does not give me possibility to use winforms. Well, `try/catch` is always there...

Comment: also +1 for you for not just wrapping your code in `try/catch` and raising a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe only classes inherits from `ToolStripControlHost` have restriction of not supporting "Transparent BackColor", so it will be safe to check only when `ToolStripItem` is `ToolStripControlHost` else you can assume it is supported (test it properly though).

```
private bool SupportsTransparentBackColor(ToolStripItem item)
{
    var host = item as ToolStripControlHost;
    if (host != null)
    {
        return SupportsTransparentBackColor(host.Control);
    }
    return true;
}

private bool SupportsTransparentBackColor(Control control)
{
    MethodInfo getstyle = typeof(Control).GetMethod("GetStyle", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    return (bool)getstyle.Invoke(control, new object[] { ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor });
}

bool textboxResult = SupportsTransparentBackColor(textBox1);//false
bool labelResult = SupportsTransparentBackColor(label1);//true
```

where `textBox1` is instance of `TextBox` and `label1` is instance of `Label`

Comment: Since `e.Item` is a `ToolStripItem` and not a `Control`, how can I make this work without a lot of additional checks?

Comment: Updated my answer, check whether that meets your requirement'

Comment: At first glance, that looks like a winner.  Thank you.